# Hyperlink to a new page and move to the specific location of that new page, possible?

Tags: html

We all know hyperlink get us a new page in the link.
Also, we all know within a page, there is "#" for us to use 
to locate the specific place for us to navigate.

What if we combine these two. jump into a new page showing 
with the specific place in that page.
Is it possible?

```
--------------------------------------------------------
< Test_01.html >

<a href="Test_02.html#005">link_goes_to_005_location </a>  -- user clicks hyperlink

--------------------------------------------------------
< Test_02.html >

001,
002,
003,
004,
<a href="#005">005</a>,  
-- not only move to the Test_02.html but also, view stops here(assuming 001-007, each one with height of 200px image). is it possible?
006,
007,
```

---

It doesn't work for me. internet explorer latest -
Then, is there any way it can be worked? 
Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you just want a link to navigate to a specific anchor on another page. If that's the case, then you can just combine them as you've suggested:

```
<a href="Test_02.html#someAnchor">Jump to someAnchor on Test_02.html</a>
```

That should work, assuming there is some element in `Test_02.html` with an `id` matching the anchor specified after the `#`:

```
<a id="someAnchor">Anchor point in Test_02.html</a>
```

Comment: You don't need `href="#"` to create an anchor.

Comment: You're right. In fact, it's going to cause problems having it there since a click on the link would return you to the top of the document. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible, however it may not work perfectly due to images loading.

The browser has two options:

- Wait for all images and dynamic content to load, then move the view to the anchored location
- Move the view immediately

In the former, the user sees the top of the page for some time, then gets jumped to the anchored position - bad experience.
In the latter, there is the risk of the "correct position" no longer being correct.

Also, if you have the problem, try clicking in the URL bar and hitting Enter - this will "reload" the anchor position and move the page correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got lost halfway through your post, but yes, it is possible to combine both navigation methods. Here is simple example that will move you to page test2.html to section marked as 002:

```
<a href="test2.html#002>link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use <a name="001"></a> before images.... give the link as <a href="Test_02.html#001">...</a>